# How to download average world GDP per capita (constant 2015 US$) by using WDI

Tags: r

I'm a new beginner of R.I want to use WDI to download global GDP per capita (constant 2015 US$) , like this figure. But I don't know how to define "country" in wdi. I only get all country of GDP, but I can't get global data.

[image]

```
global_gdp <- WDI(indicator = "NY.GDP.PCAP.KD", start = 1990, end = 2019)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you call the data from WDI, could you sum it within R and plot from there?

Rough example (haven't checked for accuracy):

```
# Import libraries.

library(WDI)
library(tidyverse)

# Call data from WDI package.

global_gdp <- WDI(
  country = "all",
  indicator = "NY.GDP.PCAP.KD",
  start = 1990,
  end = 2019,
)

# Add together the country data by year.

global_gdp2 <- global_gdp %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise((count = sum(NY.GDP.PCAP.KD, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  rename(count = c(2))

# Plot the resulting data.

ggplot(data = global_gdp2, mapping = aes(x = year, y = count)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! But I found a problem, the average world GDP per capita calculated by R is different from the average world GDP per capita in WORLD bank. I guess it is because the world bank did some Weighted Average

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from R studio community:

```
global_gdp <- WDI(
  country = "1W",
  indicator = "NY.GDP.PCAP.KD",
  start = 1990,
  end = 2019,
)
```